# Where is the ASP.NET MVC AJAX documentation?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Does anyone know where you can find online documentation for the AJAX used in ASP.NET MVC Framework Beta? I can't seem to find it. I've been looking at the [quickstarts](http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/mvc/mvc_AddingAjaxScriptsWalkthrough.htm) for some information and googling for it but seems to be very difficult to find.

It seems somewhat limited as it is now. Do people use this or do it in combination with other AJAX frameworks such as [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With MVC, jQuery would be the first choice (IMO). This has [intellisense in VS2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx), and is very widely used, so easy to get samples, and [fairly well documented](http://docs.jquery.com/).

You might also be interested in:

- [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/)
- [ASP.NET MVC in Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo/)

Comment: Oh, there is a free sample chapter on AJAX in ASP.NET MVC at the second link. Thanks!